# EntityManagerFactory is closed, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, jpa, entitymanager

I have recently created a web service that uses a static method in Java to obtain a list of items from the database.

The web service works perfectly and returns JSON back to the caller. However, it works only once. If you try to refresh or make a new request, I get a `EntityManagerFactory is closed` error.

Here's how the Web Service class looks like:

```
public class WebService extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    //obtain the list of vehicles from the database
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = ExecuteVehicle.getVehicleList();

        //create the Gson object and generate the Json
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(vehicles, new TypeToken<List<Vehicle>>(){}.getType());

        //send the list of vehicles
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the list of vehicles is being populated using the `ExecuteVehicle.getVehicleList()` method.

Here's how that method looks like:

```
public static List<Vehicle> getVehicleList(){

    //open a Session
    Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    //start a transaction
    session.beginTransaction();

    //SELECT STATEMENT for the entire list of Vehicles
    Query<Vehicle> query = session.getNamedQuery("SelectAllVehicles"); //query name is declared in the mapping file
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = query.list();

    //commit the changes and end the transaction
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    //close the Session
    session.close();

    //close the SessionFactory
    HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();

    return vehicles;
}
```

Here's the HibernateUtilities class that takes care of the Session and so on:

```
public class HibernateUtilities {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry;

    static{
        try {
            //configure and build the service registry
            standardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

            //create the metadata
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

            //build the SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            //in case the SessionFactory cannot be built, then the stackTrace is displayed
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }

    //method that returns the Hibernate session factory
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

The question I have is - how can I avoid the `EntityManagerFactory is closed` error. Furthermore, I will have to obtain this list again and again, in a real time manner. Is that feasible with Hibernate? To obtain a list of items from a database in a real-time manner (say, every 2 seconds or so)? I know this depends on the number of items and so on, but I'm asking from a technical standpoint - from what I understand, opening and closing the Session takes a long time - could I do this over and over again in the same Session and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that you are doing too much there.

You have to flush/commit the transaction and close the session as you are using the `openSession()` method of the factory.

But i dont think you need to close the SessionFactory itself

```
//close the SessionFactory
HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().close();
```

remove this line and you can would be able to use the factory many times.

Comment: It seems you're absolutely right. The interesting thing is that I tried this in the past and it didn't work. There's a possibility I've also removed (commented out) the `session.close();` line of code.

I'm pretty much a complete beginner in Hibernate and don't know exactly what all these things do, the only thing I can do is to "guess" or search in tutorials what exactly they do.

Anyway, it seems to work now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, is there any "danger" to leave the SessionFactory open? Should I worry about that in any way?

Comment: In all the application i have worked with, the SessionFActory has been created once during the startup and was destroyed only when the application has been closed.. Creating the Factory is a very intenside process and once it has been created, i would leave it alone. You have to close your sessions as they are stateful but the factory is stateless so it does not need to recreated per-request.

Comment: I see. Well, my thinking was that since I had the line `//open a Session
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();` - there shouldn't be any problem in re-opening the session. If anything, it should be very slow, since it opens and closes and opens and closes the SessionFactory, but it shouldn't crash, since the opening session factory code is the first in the method.

I wonder why the opening session code doesn't work anymore after it works the first time.

Comment: You open the session.. but you close the factory at the end.. you cannot create any more sessions when the factory is closed

Comment: So in that case, the method `HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();` doesn't really "open" the Factory, it just "gets" it, it gets the access to the factory that has been created in the static block of the `HibernateUtilities` class. I think I understand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome. Glad i could help